# Error with system() in c++ when copying a folder from a USB to a folder

Tags: c++, cmd, usb, system, xcopy

I am trying to copy the contents of a file from a USB to a folder on the PC, then start a file in it. ExePath() just returns the path.

```
system((std::string("cd c:/ && mkdir newFile && XCOPY ") + ExePath().at(0) + ":/programFile C:/newFile /i && start c:/newFile/program.exe").c_str());
```

The error I'm getting is "Invalid number of perimeters" for the xcopy part. Additionally, this creates the newFile folder in the folder where the program is located, not in C:/.
Is there a way to fix this, or is there some way to accomplish this in an easier way?

Comment: Try `std::cout << std::string("cd c:/ && mkdir newFile && XCOPY ") + ExePath().at(0) + ":/programFile C:/newFile /i && start c:/newFile/program.exe";`

Comment: Since you are using full paths anyway, you should get rid of `cd c:/` and use `mkdir C:/newFile` instead. Better, don't use `system()` for this at all, use more appropriate platform functions to make a directory and copy files into it.